# Erro na filtragem de pesquisa (PHP)

Tags: php

Eu tenho dois inputs date que é pra pegar a data que recebe deles e fazer uma pesquisa no db para mostrar todos os produtos comprados durante essa data, mas fica dando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\config\filtro.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\home.php(74): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\config\filtro.php on line 15
> ```

**Aqui vai o html dos inputs:**

```
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="center port-1 page-header">Portal Guido</h1>
        <!-- -->
        <div class="jumbotron jumb-1">
          <h4 class="center">Informe a data desejada para a busca dos produtos</h4><br>
              <form class="form-inline text-center" method="">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="datainicial">Data inicial</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inicio" name="inicio" placeholder="Data de inicio">
                </div>
                <!-- -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="datafinal">Data final</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fim" name="fim" placeholder="Data final">
                </div>
                <!-- -->
                <button type="submit" id="filtro" name="filtro" value="filtro" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Buscar
                </button>
                                <?php
                      include "config/filtro.php";
                     ?>
              </form>
        </div>
</div> <!--MAIN -->
```

**Aqui vai o código de como to pegando os dados e tentando puxar no db:**

```
<?php

require_once "config/conexao.php";

if (isset($_REQUEST['filtro'])) {

    $inicio = $_REQUEST['inicio'];
    $fim = $_REQUEST['fim'];

    $query = "SELECT * from api_teste WHERE DATEV BETWEEN date('$inicio') AND date('$fim')";


    $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if(mysqli_result($querySelect) == true){
      $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Há!</div>";
      printf ($mensagem);
    }else {
      $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Por favor coloque uma data válida!</div>";
      printf ($mensagem);
  }
}

 ?>
```

**CÓDIGO DE CONEXÃO:**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Falha ao conectar!, Motivo: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**Alguém sabe pq nao ta funcionando e como ajeitar?**
**No db o DATEV ta como date**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem diz `Call to undefined function mysqli_result in 
[...]filtro.php:15`. Ou seja a função `mysqli_result` não existe.

Isso ocorreu pois não existe mesmo a função `mysql_result`. Na verdade o retorno da função `mysqli_query` é um **objeto** do tipo `mysqli_result` (apenas em casos de consultas *SELECT, SHOW, EXPLAIN e DESCRIBE*). Para corrigir o problema, basta trocar o seu código para:

```
$querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rows = $querySelect->fetch_assoc();

if(count($rows) > 0){
```

Para mais detalhes, leia a documentação:

- [Documentação PHP: mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
- [Documentação PHP: mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

---

**PS:** Eu recomendo utilizar uma biblioteca que facilite a conexão com o banco de dados, tem uma que eu escrevi, mas sinta-se a vontade para pesquisar outra:

- [ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi)

Pode ser que ela esteja um pouco desatualizada, pois eu parei de utilizar o MySQLi e comecei a usar PDO ([ConnectionPDO](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO))

Comment: a minha versao é a 7.1.9 então ta certo

Comment: @Maria a função foi removida na versão 7. Veja a resposta novamente com mais atenção na linha que cita tal versão.

Comment: Mas é que eu fiz essa função em outro arquivo e funciona normalmente, tende? nao da nenhum erro

Comment: A connection string está correcta?

Comment: Hmmm, vc está utilizando o `mysqli_query`? Consegue colocar o código de conexão (não esqueça de remover IP, usuário e senha antes de postar), @Maria?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, sim, uso o mysqli_query. Atualizei a pergunta com o código de conexao

Comment: @Maria resposta atualizada. Veja se consegue resolver agora.

Comment: @KaduAmaral fica dando esse erro nesse if `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\config\filtro.php on line 16`

Comment: Oi @Maria, é só o `;` que eu tinha esquecido, arrumei lá. Sempre quando der um erro, lembre-se de verificar a linha do erro e a linha anterior e veja se a sintaxe está correta.

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca MySQLi não possui a função `mysqli_result`. Na realidade, [ela é uma classe](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) que é retornada pelo método [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) ou pelo método [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) (quando utilizado um *prepared statement*).

**Mysqli_query return value**:

> Returns FALSE on failure. **For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object**. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

**Mysqli_stmt::get_result**:

> **Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries**, or FALSE for other DML queries or on failure. The mysqli_errno() function can be used to distinguish between the two types of failure.

O que você está fazendo é cair no erro de transcrever um script utilizando funções `mysql_*` para a biblioteca `mysqli`. Elas são parecidas, mas não são 1:1.

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o retorno imediato de `mysqli_query`, que retorna um objeto `mysqli_result`, e iterar sobre o resultado utilizando alguma função `fetch`, tal qual a [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Versão orientada à objetos:

```
$querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = $querySelect->fetch_assoc())
{
    //iteração de cada resultado
}
```

Versão procedural:

```
$querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySelect))
{
    //iteração de cada resultado
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$ _REQUEST, por defeito, contém o conteúdo de $ _GET, $ _POST e $ _COOKIE.

Mas é apenas um padrao, que depende de variáveis_order; e não sei se pretende trabalhar com cookies.

Se eu tivesse que escolher, provavelmente não usaria $ _REQUEST e escolheria $ _GET ou $ _POST, dependendo do que pretendia que a minha aplicação fizesse (ou seja, um ou outro, mas não ambos).

Posto isto, deve usar:

- $ _GET quando alguém está solicitando dados da sua aplicação e deve
  usar
- $ _POST quando alguém está empurrando (inserindo ou atualizando
  ou excluindo) dados para sua aplicação.

De qualquer forma, não haverá muita diferença em relação aos desempenhos: a diferença será insignificante, em comparação com o que o resto do script fará.

```
<?php

include "config/conexao.php";

if (isset($_GET['filtro'])) {

    $inicio = $_GET["inicio"];
    $fim =$_GET["fim"];

    $query = "SELECT * from api_teste WHERE DTAENTORC BETWEEN date('$inicio') AND date('$fim')";


    $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if(mysqli_result($querySelect) == true){
      $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Há!</div>";
      printf ($mensagem);
    }else {
      $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Por favor coloque uma data válida!</div>";
      printf ($mensagem);
  }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: continua dando erro Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\config\filtro.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\home.php(74): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ComFiltro\config\filtro.php on line 15